# Compare values in a Dictionary and in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x

I want to loop over every key and every value of each and compare the value with a specific column of a data frame, however, I can only compare with the index of the value not the real data

```
{1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 2: [1, 2, 3, 6, 7], 3: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]}
```

here is the data frame that I am talking about.

```
   id  course_id  weight
0   1          1      10
1   2          1      40
2   3          1      50
3   4          2      40
4   5          2      60
5   6          3      90
6   7          3      10
```

I want o be able to compare,for example, the value 1 in the list at each key with the id in my data frame.
If you can explain the algorithm, I will be able to make it work after that. I tried to find an answer but I have difficulty to apply what I saw.

Comment: Can you explain better what do you want to do (including the expected output)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you check whether all the values of the series 'id' are equal to the values of the dict entry '1':

```
pd.Series(df['id'] == d[1]).all()  # True
```

If you want to see which entries differ, you can simply do:

```
df['id'] == d[1]  # pd.Series([True,True,True,True,True,True,True])
```

`d` here is your dictionary and `df` your dataframe.